# How to separate elements on the jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

If I have a code like this

```
<div class="size">
       <a class="cm active" data-id="cm">CM</a> /* ACTIVE */
       <a class="inch" data-id="inch">INCH</a>
</div>
<div class="button">
       <li data-head-cm="ABC" data-head-inch="DEF"
          data-body-cm="GHI" data-body-inch="JKL"
          class="active">                       /* ACTIVE */
               BUTTON 1
       </li>
       <li data-foot-cm="MNO" data-foot-inch="PQR"
          data-hair-cm="STU" data-hair-inch="VWX">
               BUTTON 2
       </li>
       <li data-head-cm="ABC" data-head-inch="DEF"
          data-body-cm="GHI" data-body-inch="JKL"
          data-hair-cm="STU" data-hair-inch="VWX">
               BUTTON 3
       </li>
</div>
<ul class="diagram">
</ul>
```

So, the name of the element part of the body (hair/foot/body/head), will go into the `ID` and value element data (ex : `="ABC"`) will enter goto `<li>ABC</li>`

Code will change when I click on one of the buttons

```
/* if click BUTTON 1, diagram ul. Create element <li> */
<ul class="diagram">
       <li id="head">ABC</li>
       <li id="body">GHI</li>
</ul>

/* if click BUTTON 2, diagram ul. Create element <li> */
<ul class="diagram">
       <li id="foot">MNO</li>
       <li id="hair">STU</li>
</ul>

/* if click BUTTON 3, diagram ul. Create element <li> */
<ul class="diagram">
       <li id="head">ABC</li>
       <li id="body">GHI</li>
       <li id="hair">STU</li>
</ul>
```

And when I click on the `size`. then the value of that data element that ends `-inch` be replaced. Depending on the active element

```
/* if click BUTTON 2 AND SIZE ACTIVED CLASS INCH, diagram ul. Create element <li> */
<ul class="diagram">
       <li id="foot">PQR</li>
       <li id="hair">VWX</li>
</ul>
```

I worked only like this https://jsfiddle.net/rwvmacjs/4/. How to be like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rwvmacjs/8/

```
$(document).on('click', '.button li', function(e) {
    $('.button li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $("ul.diagram").html('');
    var sizeVal = $(".size a.active").data('id');

    var ulHtml = "";

    var dataAttrs = $(this).data();

    for(x in dataAttrs) {
      var attrDetail = x.toLowerCase().split(sizeVal);
      if(attrDetail.length > 1) {
        ulHtml += '<li id="'+attrDetail[0]+'">'+dataAttrs[x]+'</li>';
      }
    }
    $("ul.diagram").html(ulHtml);
});
```

Comment: whether it can replace the parts of the body? Because there are 40 body parts. (hair head body foot). Create minimaze